# Android if rectangle contains touch coords then add to array giving weird output

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am building a game that you drag your finger in a sequence from one block to the next.

What I need to happen: when they hover over a block, it adds that block number to an array so I know in which sequence the blocks were touched in. it needs to be dragged from block to block, not clicked (sort of like the android lockscreen app).

What I am doing so far: creating a rectangle for each block using its coordinates and dimensions, then I am checking that if the user's touch is within that rectangle, add that block number to the array.

It seems to be working, but it only works for buttons 1, 2 and 3 (Only 1, 2 and 3 will be added to the array) But if I `log` the touch to `logcat` and the buttons dimensions / coordinates, it is picking the thing up, so I don't know why it is not holding the information?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    x = (int) arg1.getX();
    y = (int) arg1.getY();

    if(b1R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("1");
    } else if(b2R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("2");
    } else if(b3R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("3");
    } else if(b4R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("4");
    } else if(b5R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("5");
    } else if(b6R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("6");
    } else if(b7R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("7");
    } else if(b8R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("8");
    } else if(b9R.contains(x,y)){
        arr.add("9");
    }

    if(arr.toString() != null){
        Log.d("log", arr.toString());
        Log.d("x", ""+x);
        Log.d("y", ""+y);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        b1R = new Rect(b1.getLeft(), b1.getTop(), b1.getRight(), b1.getBottom());
        b2R = new Rect(b2.getLeft(), b2.getTop(), b2.getRight(), b2.getBottom());
        b3R = new Rect(b3.getLeft(), b3.getTop(), b3.getRight(), b3.getBottom());
        b4R = new Rect(b4.getLeft(), b4.getTop(), b4.getRight(), b4.getBottom());
        b5R = new Rect(b5.getLeft(), b5.getTop(), b5.getRight(), b5.getBottom());
        b6R = new Rect(b6.getLeft(), b6.getTop(), b6.getRight(), b6.getBottom());
        b7R = new Rect(b7.getLeft(), b7.getTop(), b7.getRight(), b7.getBottom());
        b8R = new Rect(b8.getLeft(), b8.getTop(), b8.getRight(), b8.getBottom());
        b9R = new Rect(b9.getLeft(), b9.getTop(), b9.getRight(), b9.getBottom());
    }
}
```

this is what is being printed to `logcat`:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3]
```

and no other buttons?

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is B1r?  Should you be updating this at some point to account for a new set of locations?  You're using Else If statements, which means that as long as

```
if(b1R.contains(x,y)){
```

Evaluates to true, none of your other checks will execute.

I would ensure that you don't have b1r's bounds set to the entire screen, or some other incorrect (or possibly "correct" but damaging value).

It's hard to really debug this without more code however.